# How do I smoothen the edges of a radar chart in chart js?

Tags: javascript, radar-chart, chartjs-2.6.0

I'm trying to make a radar chart with smooth edges as in the Chart JS sample of a radar chart

http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/area/radar.html

I tried looking for it in the documentation and figured that it could be lineTension property however I still couldn't make it work. I'm new to JS so i'm probably doing something wrong. Can someone show me an example?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source in your link, the relevant code is here:

```
chart.options.elements.line.tension = value ? 0.4 : 0.000001;
chart.update();
```

So setting `chart.options.elements.line.tension` to `0.4` and then calling `chart.update();` should work